# ActiveRecord and Filtered Subquery

Tags: sql, activerecord

I have two models:

```
model Agent
  has_many :backups
end

model Backup
  belongs_to :agent

  # verification_status, :boolean
end
```

Each Backup represents a performed backup job. The log may contain a verification status. Either the verification Failed (stored as false) or Succeeded (stored as true). But not every backup email includes a verification status** (stored as null).

** You may backup the server hourly, but only do a verification once per 24 hours.

I need to pull the last true/false verification status for each agent, and ideally only need to report on the false.

```
Backup.find_by_sql("
  select agents.name, 
         latest_failures.verification_status 
    from (select agent_id, MAX(timestamp), verification_status 
            from backups 
           where verification_status is false 
           group by agent_id) as latest_failures 
   inner join agents on agents.id = latest_failures.agent_id 
   where agents.is_paused='f' 
     and agents.is_archived='f'
")
```

This appears to return way too many results, i.e. 1,300 agents are showing the last backup status is false, when typically it is under 100 and any given time.

Can someone point out the error in my SQL. I believe I am skipping over the trues to find the last false and including it in my total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was close:

```
Backup.find_by_sql("
  select agents.name, 
         latest_failures.verification_status 
    from (select agent_id, 
                 MAX(timestamp), 
                 verification_status 
            from backups 
           where verification_status is not null 
           group by agent_id) as latest_failures 
   inner join agents 
      on agents.id = latest_failures.agent_id 
   where agents.is_paused='f' 
     and agents.is_archived='f' 
     and latest_failures.screenshot_status = 'f'
")
```

First, get the latest non-null value for each agent, and then filter for just the failures in the outer query.